# Adobe Illustrator Zoom around selected, not to screen centre?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, zoom

Command (Cntrl) and = gives zoom in, in Adobe Illustrator.

Is there a way to set it so that it zooms to the selected object rather than the centre of the screen?

Comment: For me (CC) it zooms not to the center of the screen but to the mouse location. Presumably that's not what you're looking for either?

Comment: How did you get that turned on? I don't have that, at all. It's not ideal, but it's better than the blind centre zoom.

Comment: Oops, didn't read your question properly. To zoom, I always use Cmd/Ctrl + Alt + Mouse Scroll, that will zoom in on the mouse pointer's location. I have the same behavior as you for Cmd/Ctrl + =

Comment: Yeah, mouse wheel and two finger does that, but I'm trying to get object zoom. It seems like such a logical thing to have... but... no.

Comment: It's the norm in Indesign/PS — with an object selected you hit command + 1 to go to 100% view with the zoom centered on selected object. It's far quicker to toggle between a zoomed mode and 100% with a keystroke than it is to futz with a scroll wheel + modifier (the amount of precision to get that right is ridiculous) or command + space... or the navigation panel. Why the Adobe Illustrator design team thinks it's better for that zoom to be based on the art board AND ALSO not give the user the option to customize, is a mystery to me.

Comment: LOL and immediately as hey made this possible somebody immediately had a problem with it. So bad move.

Comment: What are you talking about @joojaa? Has Adobe added this to the latest CC?

Comment: Yes [see this](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/81902/adobe-illustrator-21-0-0-how-to-zoom-in-out-on-mouse-and-not-on-selected-obj) And immediately people were asking for the old behaviour.

Comment: This is classic Adobe! They have been doing this sort of thing with AE forever. What prevents them from making a mode switch? Hey, users, there's this: 1. Old style zoom. 2. Hey, presto, the way zoom should work, as it does in all decent design apps. Dear customers, take your choice. ---- No... they can't admit to their mistake, so remove the old one, and don't announce the new way, pissing off everyone with muscle memory and workarounds. Which is EVERYONE, in this case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I built the following scripts to replace Ctrl+1 (zoom to 100%).
When nothing is selected, it will center the view to centerpoint of active artboard.
When one or more elements are selected, it will center the view on the object(s) centerpoint.

---

#### UPDATE:

GitHub repo created to host these adobe scripts to handle the functionality described:

- [Zoom: 100% and Center Selection](https://github.com/stev0thegreat/adobe-scripts/blob/master/center-selection.jsx)
- [Zoom to Fit Selection (+ padding) in Viewport and Center](https://github.com/stev0thegreat/adobe-scripts/blob/master/fit-and-center.jsx)

Save the linked code into your scripts folder (assuming default install location of Adobe 2017 for Windows 10): `C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Illustrator CC 2017\Presets\en_US\Scripts`.

---

*Additional note: I've also created some `AutoHotkey` scripts to help Windows users with creation of hotkeys to execute these scripts easier. I'll update this post when they've been added to the repo.

Comment: Is it possible to make this centre the view to the current object and "zoom to fill" the screen with that current object?

Comment: @Confused certainly possible I think I'll put this in a GitHub repo so I can iterate on it and take addition requests there. I'll provide a link shortly.

Comment: YOU ARE A LEGEND!!! Buy yourself a round of Tooheys Old.

Comment: link to repo: https://github.com/stev0thegreat/adobe-scripts/blob/master/viewport-center-selection.jsx

Comment: a man with good code stylings, too. Upgrade that Tooheys Old to a Guinness, and call it a day!

Comment: Updated the original post with repo urls for both zoom to 100% and fit viewport to selection (+ a little padding);

I'd take you up on the Guinness anyday :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49850/discussion-between-stev0thegreat-and-confused).

Answer (score 10):

### 2016 UPDATE:

**Illustrator CC** now has the ability to smooth zoom.

If your graphics card supports it - just hold <kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Spacebar</kbd> and move the cursor over the area you want to zoom in to... That's all there is to it.

---

**Pre-CC** answer.....

No. Illustrator provides no mechanism to "zoom to selected".

It may be possible via scripting.

However.....

You can temporarily access the **Zoom Tool** by holding the <kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Spacebar</kbd> key combination. This will allow you to draw a rectangle around what you want to zoom in on. (Add <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd> and it becomes Zoom Out.) Then just hit <kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> to zoom to page again. Pressing <kbd>Z</kbd> toggles the magnifying glass tool to give the same functionality without holding down buttons, but will require switching tools after (probably <kbd>A</kbd> or <kbd>V</kbd> for most things.)

And you may find the **Navigator Panel** (`Window > Navigator`) handy. It's designed to move the "zoom" around with a click-drag in the panel.

You can also open an additional window for the document you are working on via `Window > New Window`. With this option you can set the zoom differently for each window allowing you to work zoomed in, then view the art zoomed out, without the need to continually zoom in and out. Changes in one window are reflected in both windows.

Comment: Thanks. None of those help me, I'm looking for something super quick to go in and out on different objects as I select them, as and when I want to assess, edit, assess, edit... etc. Just another reason to despise the UX of AI.

Comment: @Confused added key combo which may help (it's what I use).

Comment: I know all these, they're kind of universal-ish. It's just that a few other apps I use zoom to selected, or have zoom to extents of selected built in. Thought for sure Illustrator would have something like it. But was being optimistic.

Comment: Smooth Zoom is not the same as "zoom to selection".

Comment: Agreed.. but smooth zoom is pretty darn close since you target the zoom with the cursor position.

Answer (score 5):

Using the <kbd>Alt</kbd> modifier key and the <kbd>Scroll wheel</kbd>, you can zoom around the mouse pointer. Point at what you want to zoom into, and use this shortcut key combination to zoom.

Comment: Closest answer for me, but with apple mouse it's pretty bad. Still can't really believe there's no option to enable this like in Sketch, or even Fireworks.

Answer (score 3):

Zoom to selected is a great feature that I also use constantly on other design programs...the closest I can find in illustrator is to assign a hotkey to "Object >> Artboards >> Fit to selected art" which creates an artboard around your selected object and then you can use the hotkey (CTRL + 0 on mine) to "Zoom to Artboard"...I know this is not ideal because you end up creating a bunch of useless artboards but it is the closest way I can find to duplicate the effect...my latest problem is I realized that it zooms differently if I am in outline mode or preview mode. After pressing 'z' for the 'Zoom tool' I get marquee zoom in outline mode and "scrubby zoom" in preview mode...can't find settings to change either...baffles me how core functionality like this is still not right after all these versions...

Answer (score 3):

I got the proper solution from the very easy script **Zoom Selection** which can be downloaded [from here](http://vectorboom.com/load/freebies/freescripts/zoom_selection_a_free_script_for_adobe_illustrator/22-1-0-573).

> The script Zoom Selection (developed by John Wundes) is designed for instant zooming in of the objects to a full screen. This feature will help you quickly view and edit objects.

Answer (score 2):

if anyone else is looking for a quick way to locate or **zoom to a selection / layer in the viewport**, you can do this without scripts in Illustrator CC by creating an automated Action.

Works on text too!

Use the **Insert Menu Item...** option  in the drawer menu to choose or type these steps instead of recording them.

- Fit to Selected Art
- Fit Artboard in Window
- Undo

What this does is

1. Resize the current artboard to your selection
2. Zoom viewport in on the modified artboard (Ctrl + 0)
3. Undo and change the artboard back!

[image: Zoom to Layer Action]

[image: Insert Menu Items]

Comment: Abusing the Artboard, very good lateral thinking!

Comment: Thanks for this. Tip while building this action: put an immediately recognizable Undo in your current document ahead of time. While testing the action I inadvertently undid a bunch of edits I needed to keep and recreating them was a pain.

Answer (score 1):

Bobby Zopfan has posted an excellent solution:

> I got the proper solution from the very easy script Zoom Selection which can be downloaded from here.
>
> The script Zoom Selection (developed by John Wundes) is designed for instant zooming in of the objects to a full screen. This feature will help you quickly view and edit objects.

I'd like to add that it is possible to create a shortcut in illustrator for running a script in Mac. You use AUTOMATOR!

1. Create a new **Service**
2. Service receives **[no input]** in [Adobe Illustrator CC 2017.app]
3. Search and add Action: **Get Specified Finder Items**.
   Add the downloaded .jsx script here.
4. Search and add action: **Open Finder Items**.
   Open with: "Adobe Illustrator CC 2017.app"
5. Save service: <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> Use a name, best e.g. ZOOM SELECTION
6. Go to OSX **System preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts**
7. You find your script under Services. Z makes it to be at the bottom
8. Add a shortcut for it. I suggest <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>

Relaunch Illustrator and voila!

Word of caution: This is an action in system keyboard shortcuts! It is not restricted to Illustrator, alas, I don't know of any software that uses <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> for anything. I suggest that you do NOT assign an F key.

Comment: Xcode uses [command + shift + 0] to show the documentation window, probably the third most used window of Xcode, right below Safari ;)

Answer (score 1):

I have the latest version and had the same problem. In the latest I went to Preferences, Performance and turned off Animated Zoom

Answer (score 1):

I heavily modified https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/81334/75091 / https://github.com/iholler/adobe-scripts/blob/master/fit-and-center.jsx to create this script: (the colors and shapes and commented-out code are for debugging)

```js
/******************************************************************************
>> Center Viewport - Zoom to Fit (+ a little padding for aesthetics)
******************************************************************************/

var
    topL_X,
    topL_Y,
    botR_X,
    botR_Y,
    document = app.activeDocument,
    view = document.activeView,
    currentViewBounds = view.bounds,
    selection = document.selection,
    padding = 0.05;

var cyan = new CMYKColor();
cyan.cyan = 100;
var magenta = new CMYKColor();
magenta.magenta = 100;
var yellow = new CMYKColor();
yellow.yellow = 100;


function createRectangleFromBounds(bounds) {
    return document.pathItems.rectangle((bounds[1], bounds[3]), (bounds[0], bounds[2]), (bounds[0] - bounds[2]), (bounds[3] - bounds[1]));
}

function applyColors(rect, strokeColor, fillColor) {
    rect.strokeColor = strokeColor;
    rect.fillColor = fillColor;
}


if(selection.length > 0) {
    var objectBounds = selection[0].controlBounds;
    topL_X = objectBounds[0];
    topL_Y = objectBounds[1];
    botR_X = objectBounds[2];
    botR_Y = objectBounds[3];

    for(var i in selection) {
        objectBounds = selection[i].controlBounds;

        //applyColors(createRectangleFromBounds(objectBounds), yellow, NoColor);

        topL_X = Math.min(topL_X, objectBounds[0]);
        topL_Y = Math.max(topL_Y, objectBounds[1]);
        botR_X = Math.max(botR_X, objectBounds[2]);
        botR_Y = Math.min(botR_Y, objectBounds[3]);
    }
} else {
    var artboard = document.artboards[document.artboards.getActiveArtboardIndex()];

    topL_X = artboard.artboardRect[0];
    topL_Y = artboard.artboardRect[1];
    botR_X = artboard.artboardRect[2];
    botR_Y = artboard.artboardRect[3];
}

//applyColors(createRectangleFromBounds([topL_X, topL_Y, botR_X, botR_Y]), cyan, NoColor);
//applyColors(createRectangleFromBounds(currentViewBounds), magenta, NoColor);

view.zoom = view.zoom / (1 + padding) * Math.min(Math.abs(currentViewBounds[2] - currentViewBounds[0]) / Math.abs(botR_X - topL_X),
                                                 Math.abs(currentViewBounds[3] - currentViewBounds[1]) / Math.abs(botR_Y - topL_Y));
view.centerPoint = [(topL_X + botR_X) / 2, (topL_Y + botR_Y) / 2];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just select an object and then press ctrl+ it will immediately center that object and zoom in one increment. From there, 99% of the time it takes between 1-3 more presses of the + key (or - key if for some odd reason you're selecting an object that is already overflowing the working area) for the object to roughly fill your working space. More often than not it's only 2 more presses. This way seems easies

Answer (score -2):

it is in Preferences -> GPU Performance, you have to uncheck "Enable Animated Zoom"

Comment: How does this answer the question? According to [the online Help](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/kb/gpu-performance-preview-improvements.html) you can "Select this check box to enable zoom actions to appear smooth and animated."

Answer (score -3):

I got my zoom back!
It's called GPU preview [⌘E] Sorry, I don't know for PC.

It zooms in/out by click and drags the mouse. I hope this helps fix some of you guys problems!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lip_g8mbpvg

https://youtu.be/rsPqOtw37OQ?t=138