# Adobe Illustrator 21.0.0 - How to Zoom In / Out on Mouse and Not on Selected Object / Area

Tags: adobe-illustrator, selections, zoom

This started happening when I recently updated to Adobe Illustrator 21.0.0 (2017 release). Simply, if I select an object and then move over to another area of the document:

[image]

[image]

and then try to zoom in or out to inspect that area,

[image]

it brings me right back to the area with the selected object. This is already annoying, but it becomes a real problem when I want to move several selected objects at the same time.

For example, if I want to adjust the position of every object within an artboard, I would select all of the objects and start to move them with the up, down, left, right arrow keys.

[image]

[image]

[image]

As soon as I try to zoom in on an area to see if the objects are lining up within the artboard, it brings me back to a random area in the selected group (in this case, an area at the bottom and opposite end of where I'd like to zoom in).

[image]

Trying to move back the area I'd like to zoom into....

[image]

Zoom in (command +)

[image]

and I'm brought back to the area at the bottom. Even if I deselect all of the objects in the area that it keeps zooming into, it still defaults back to that area when I try to zoom in.

[image]

[image]

[image]

And of course I can't select half of the objects if I'm trying to move all of them in unison.

Is there any way to tell Illustrator that I'd like to zoom in on the area where my mouse is, regardless of whether or not something else is selected?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! I've been experiencing this too and miss the old zoom functionality. There is a discussion on it in Adobe forums here:
https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2230942

The consensus seems to be that zooming to the selection is a new feature update. And our best option right now is to use the Feature Request/Bug Report form to get this resolved for future releases:
http://www.adobe.com/products/wishform.html

Comment: Glad I'm not the only one experiencing this. Thanks for the link, I'll fill that out ASAP. I guess there's no way to revert to the previous version? I'd honestly like to until they get this problem fixed.

Comment: Oh! You totally can revert to old versions. In the Creative Cloud app, you can go to "Find Additional Apps" and filter by "View Previous Versions". Here's another Adobe forum reference on how to do that:
https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2170895